# Why does changing from {3} to {4} not work for this regex?

Tags: regex, grep

I have a basic IP regex that checks that an ip is within 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255. When I enter

```
grep -E "^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}" file.txt
```

It matches a total of 12 ip addresses (which is correct for my text file) but only highlights the first 3 octets when I need it to highlight the 4th octet too. But changing it "{4}" shows no matches.

```
grep -E "^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){4}" file.txt
```

My quick question is why is it not highlighting the full 4 octets as matches using `{4}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not match the fourth octet as the expression matches an octet and then `.` exactly 3 times. Since there is no `.` after the 4th octet, it is not matched, and not highlighted.

You may use

```
grep -E "((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.?){4}"
```

Here, `\.?` matches 1 or 0 `.` chars (i.e. the `.` is optional, so the 4th octet will now match and will get highlighted).

Or, a more precise pattern will also do:

```
grep -E "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}"
```

It will match and highlight the whole IP address string.

You may add anchors or word boundaries to the pattern as per your requirements. E.g. here is a word boundary pattern variation:

```
grep -E "\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\b"
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately when I implement the ''\.?'' it starts accepting wrong ip addresses such as "1334.0.1.234" and it doesn't even highlight the whole ip address, it cuts off at ''1334.0.''

Comment: Yeah, that is why I suggest a more precise pattern. If you need to make sure it matches whole words, use word boundaries.

Comment: I also tried the second pattern too as it was one that I understood the concept of and it held the same results [image of results](https://imgur.com/a/V4qsC)

Comment: @JoshuaNguyen I focused on your "highlighting" problem first. I added a pattern with word boundaries.

Comment: Yes thank you for helping me out once again. I know this may seem trivial to you but I do appreciate your time